# Wordpress: Get related posts by category, but ignore primary category

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm trying to set up related posts that show posts in the same category as the current. The way the clients blog is set up is that they all share the category "blog", the related posts will show the same thing for every post.

```
<?php $related = get_posts( array( 
                'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories($post->ID), 
                'numberposts' => 4, 
                'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
                ) );

            ?>
```

I need to get posts that aren't the primary category (Blog). I can't do "`cateogry__not__in`" because then it would exclude everything.

Comment: How about filtering `wp_get_post_categories($post->ID)` so it doesn't include the blog-category?

Comment: Can you help me go about this? I still need to make sure it's not hiding posts with category blog because they all have that category.

Comment: `'category__in' => array_diff( wp_get_post_categories($post->ID), array(5) ),`.... (where 5 is the ID of the blog category....)

Comment: Thanks, cale, but it's still returning the same set of posts for every single.php post

Comment: Well, then it sounds like your posts all are within these categories, yes? Unless you troubleshoot - share ID's of categories - the ID's of the categories for the current post, etc., this is impossible to guess.

Answer (score 0):

According to [wp_term_query's docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/), you should be able to exclude the blog by adding parameters, e.g. changing your `category__in` to

```
'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories(
    $post->ID,
    array(
        "exclude" => array($blogid)
    )
),
```

with `$blogid` being the term id of your blog category. Since it also provides `exclude_tree` to exclude terms and their child terms, I assume that it will do exactly what you want to achieve and exclude only the blog category.

Comment: unfortunately, i still seem to be getting the same 4 posts on every post (single.php). It doesn't exclude blog and look for other categories.Thanks for your help though.

Comment: What does the wp_get_post_categories-call return? Did you replace $blogid with the ID of your blog category?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I found a way. Everything seems to function the way I want.

```
 $categories = get_the_category();
 $category_filter = array();

   foreach ($categories as $category) {
     if ($category->name != "Blog") {
        array_push($category_filter, $category->term_id);
     }
  }



    <?php $related = get_posts( array( 
         'category__in' => $category_filter,
          'numberposts' => 4, 
           'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
            'orderby' => 'rand'
       ) );

     ?>
```